# Coding issue with Fast LED Multiple Colour Palettes in a State Machine

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, ws2812

I am working on a project using the WSB2812B LED strip, with a ATmega644A using the MCUdude/MightyCore plug in (https://github.com/MCUdude/MightyCore).

I am using Fastled 3.3.3 with Ardunio 1.8.13 on Windows 10 and is using code based on "ColourWavesWithPalettes" (https://gist.github.com/kriegsman/8281905786e8b2632aeb).

This project as 2 button inputs  `Solid` & `Palette` and 2 outputs, `LED DI` & `Mosfet gate`. With the sequence being the following:

1. Power on and start running a set of colour palettes with fade (STANDARD_COLOUR_PALETTE). This could be anything from 5-15 colours, with transitioning colours from red to green to blue to purple to yellow... etc.
2. If `Palette` button is pressed, then change state to run 1 colour palette with fade (SINGLE_COLOUR_PALETTE) on repeat. E.G just purple with fade.
3. While in SINGLE_COLOUR_PALETTE state, if `Palette` button is pressed then change colour to another 1 colour palette e.g blue but still in the SINGLE_COLOUR_PALETTE state.
4. If in either "STANDARD_COLOUR_PALETTE" or "SINGLE_COLOUR_PALETTE" state and `Solid` button is pressed, then change state to run 1 solid colour (SOLID_COLOUR) e.g just blue with no fade.
5. While in "STANDARD_COLOUR_PALETTE" if `Solid` button is pressed, then change to another solid colour e.g Red with no fade.
6. While in "STANDARD_COLOUR_PALETTE" if `Palette` button is pressed then change state to colour palettes with fade (STANDARD_COLOUR_PALETTE).

In summary, the code is made up of 3 states with `for` loops and `if` statements. I have most of this sequence working but I am struggling a lot with step 2 & 3, as there is only 1 colour palette "Playlist" that I am trying to use as STANDARD_COLOUR_PALETTE but also trying to pull indivduial colour palettes from (SINGLE_COLOUR_PALETT).

One solution I thought of was to generate multiple separate a colour playlists one with the 5-15 colours that would fade to one another and many more that would just have the single colour palette.

How to code that into the exiting "ColourWavesWithPalettes" I used as a base?

```cpp
#include "FastLED.h"
#if FASTLED_VERSION < 3001000
#error "Requires FastLED 3.1 or later; check github for latest code."
#endif

#define DATA_PIN    16
#define LED_TYPE    WS2812B
#define COLOR_ORDER GRB
#define NUM_LEDS    276
#define BRIGHTNESS  250
#define SECONDS_PER_PALETTE 10 // ten seconds per color palette makes a good demo but 20-120 is better for deployment
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

enum State{STANDARD_COLOUR_PALETTE, SINGLE_COLOUR_PALETTE, SOLID_COLOUR};
uint8_t State = STANDARD_COLOUR_PALETTE;
int SOLID_COLOUR_POSITION;
int SOLID_COLOUR_COUNT;
int SINGLE_COLOUR_PALETTE_COUNT;


// ten seconds per color palette makes a good demo
// 20-120 is better for deployment
#define SECONDS_PER_PALETTE 10


void setup() {
  delay(1000); // 1 second delay for recovery
  pinMode(14, INPUT); // pin #14 Solid  
  pinMode(13, INPUT); // pin #13 Palette Colour
  pinMode(17, OUTPUT); // Pin #17 MOSFET gate
  digitalWrite(17,HIGH);
  
  // tell FastLED about the LED strip configuration
  FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE,DATA_PIN,COLOR_ORDER>(leds, NUM_LEDS)
    //.setCorrection(TypicalLEDStrip) // cpt-city palettes have different color balance //TEST THIS!!!!!!
    .setDither(BRIGHTNESS < 255);

  // set master brightness control
  FastLED.setBrightness(BRIGHTNESS);
}

// Forward declarations of an array of cpt-city gradient palettes, and 
// a count of how many there are.  The actual color palette definitions
// are at the bottom of this file.
extern const TProgmemRGBGradientPalettePtr gGradientPalettes[];
extern const uint8_t gGradientPaletteCount;

// Current palette number from the 'playlist' of color palettes
uint8_t gCurrentPaletteNumber = 0;

CRGBPalette16 gCurrentPalette( CRGB::Black);
CRGBPalette16 gTargetPalette( gGradientPalettes[0] );
CRGBPalette16 gTargetPalette1( gGradientPalettes[0] );


void loop()
{

  switch (State)
  {
    case STANDARD_COLOUR_PALETTE:
        EVERY_N_SECONDS( SECONDS_PER_PALETTE ) {
        gCurrentPaletteNumber = addmod8( gCurrentPaletteNumber, 1, gGradientPaletteCount);
        gTargetPalette = gGradientPalettes[ gCurrentPaletteNumber ];
        }

        EVERY_N_MILLISECONDS(40) {
        nblendPaletteTowardPalette( gCurrentPalette, gTargetPalette, 16);
        }
  
        colorwaves( leds, NUM_LEDS, gCurrentPalette);

        FastLED.show();
        FastLED.delay(20);

        if (digitalRead(13)==HIGH) // Colour palette pressed
        {
          delay(400);
          State = SINGLE_COLOUR_PALETTE; // Change state to single colour palettes
        
        }

        if (digitalRead(14)==HIGH) // Solid colour button pressed
        {
          delay(400);
          State = SOLID_COLOUR; // Change state to solid colours
          SINGLE_COLOUR_PALETTE_COUNT =++SINGLE_COLOUR_PALETTE_COUNT;
        }
    break; //End STANDARD_COLOUR_PALETTE

    case SINGLE_COLOUR_PALETTE:
//        if (SINGLE_COLOUR_PALETTE_COUNT==1)
//        {
//        EVERY_N_SECONDS( SECONDS_PER_PALETTE ) {
//        gCurrentPaletteNumber = addmod8( gCurrentPaletteNumber, 1, gGradientPaletteCount);
//        gTargetPalette1 = gGradientPalettes[ gCurrentPaletteNumber ];
//        }
//
//        EVERY_N_MILLISECONDS(40) {
//        nblendPaletteTowardPalette( gCurrentPalette, gTargetPalette1, 16);
//        }
//  
//        colorwaves( leds, NUM_LEDS, gCurrentPalette);
//
//        FastLED.show();
//        FastLED.delay(20);
//        }

        if (digitalRead(14)==HIGH) // Solid colour button pressed
        {
          delay(400);
          State = SOLID_COLOUR; // Change state to solid colours
          SINGLE_COLOUR_PALETTE_COUNT =++SINGLE_COLOUR_PALETTE_COUNT;
        }
//
//        if (SOLID_COLOUR_COUNT==1)
//        {
//          for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) 
//          {
//            leds[i].setRGB(255, 255, 0);   
//          }      
//        }
//
//        if(digitalRead(14)==HIGH)
//        {
//          delay(100);
//          SOLID_COLOUR_COUNT=++SOLID_COLOUR_COUNT;
//        }
//        FastLED.show();
//        FastLED.delay(20);
//    break; //End SINGLE_COLOUR_PALETTE

    
    case SOLID_COLOUR:
         if (SOLID_COLOUR_COUNT==1)
        {
          for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) 
          {
            leds[i].setRGB(255, 0, 0);   
          }      
        }

        if (SOLID_COLOUR_COUNT==2)
        {
          for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) 
          {
            leds[i].setRGB(0, 255, 0);   
          }      
        }
        FastLED.show();
        FastLED.delay(20);

        if(digitalRead(14)==HIGH)
        {
          delay(400);
          SOLID_COLOUR_COUNT=++SOLID_COLOUR_COUNT;
        }

        if(digitalRead(13)==HIGH)
        {
          delay(400);
          SOLID_COLOUR_COUNT=0;
          State = STANDARD_COLOUR_PALETTE;
        }

    break; // End SOLID_COLOUR
    }// switch end

} // Main end


// This function draws color waves with an ever-changing,
// widely-varying set of parameters, using a color palette.
void colorwaves( CRGB* ledarray, uint16_t numleds, CRGBPalette16& palette) 
{
  static uint16_t sPseudotime = 0;
  static uint16_t sLastMillis = 0;
  static uint16_t sHue16 = 0;
 
  uint8_t sat8 = beatsin88( 87, 220, 250);
  uint8_t brightdepth = beatsin88( 341, 96, 224);
  uint16_t brightnessthetainc16 = beatsin88( 203, (25 * 256), (40 * 256));
  uint8_t msmultiplier = beatsin88(147, 23, 60);

  uint16_t hue16 = sHue16;//gHue * 256;
  uint16_t hueinc16 = beatsin88(113, 300, 1500);
  
  uint16_t ms = millis();
  uint16_t deltams = ms - sLastMillis ;
  sLastMillis  = ms;
  sPseudotime += deltams * msmultiplier;
  sHue16 += deltams * beatsin88( 400, 5,9);
  uint16_t brightnesstheta16 = sPseudotime;
  
  for( uint16_t i = 0 ; i < numleds; i++) {
    hue16 += hueinc16;
    uint8_t hue8 = hue16 / 256;
    uint16_t h16_128 = hue16 >> 7;
    if( h16_128 & 0x100) {
      hue8 = 255 - (h16_128 >> 1);
    } else {
      hue8 = h16_128 >> 1;
    }

    brightnesstheta16  += brightnessthetainc16;
    uint16_t b16 = sin16( brightnesstheta16  ) + 32768;

    uint16_t bri16 = (uint32_t)((uint32_t)b16 * (uint32_t)b16) / 65536;
    uint8_t bri8 = (uint32_t)(((uint32_t)bri16) * brightdepth) / 65536;
    bri8 += (255 - brightdepth);
    
    uint8_t index = hue8;
    //index = triwave8( index);
    index = scale8( index, 240);

    CRGB newcolor = ColorFromPalette( palette, index, bri8);

    uint16_t pixelnumber = i;
    pixelnumber = (numleds-1) - pixelnumber;
    
    nblend( ledarray[pixelnumber], newcolor, 128);
  }
}

// Alternate rendering function just scrolls the current palette 
// across the defined LED strip.
void palettetest( CRGB* ledarray, uint16_t numleds, const CRGBPalette16& gCurrentPalette)
{
  static uint8_t startindex = 0;
  startindex--;
  fill_palette( ledarray, numleds, startindex, (256 / NUM_LEDS) + 1, gCurrentPalette, 255, LINEARBLEND);
}





// Gradient palette "yellow_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/h5/tn/yellow.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 8 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( yellow_gp ) {
    0, 255,255,255,
  255, 255,255,  0};

  // Gradient palette "RK_Yellow_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/lb/mp/tn/RK_Yellow.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 12 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( RK_Yellow_gp ) {
    0, 239,147,  0,
  155, 247,180,  1,
  255, 252,215,  1};

  // Gradient palette "blues_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/ocal/tn/blues.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 32 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( blues_gp ) { //Blue
    0,   0,  0, 45,
   25,   0,  0,125,
   51,   0,  0,255,
   76,   7, 12,255,
  127,   7, 55,255,
  178,   0,138,255,
  242,   0,255,255,
  255, 255,255,255};


  // Gradient palette "bhw1_33_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/bhw/bhw1/tn/bhw1_33.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 16 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( bhw1_33_gp ) { //Purple
    0,   2,  1,  8,
   94,  79,  2,212,
  140, 110, 11,197,
  255,   2,  1,  8};


// Gradient palette "Fuschia_8_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/ds/fuschia/tn/Fuschia-8.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 12 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( Fuschia_8_gp ) {//Purple
    0,  44,  4,214,
  127, 123,  1,233,
  255, 255,  0,255};

// Gradient palette "Blue_Green_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/ggr/tn/Blue_Green.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 20 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( Blue_Green_gp ) { //Light blue to green
    0,   0, 51,255,
   34,   1,111,255,
  144,   9,195,255,
  234,   1,225,153,
  255,   0,255, 80};

// Gradient palette "Green_3D_1_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/sd/tn/Green-3D_1.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 28 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( Green_3D_1_gp ) {
    0, 103,186,106,
   42,  45,147, 48,
   84,  13,114, 14,
  127,   2, 87,  2,
  170,   0, 66,  0,
  212,   0, 23,  0,
  255,   0,  3,  0};

// Gradient palette "Mexican_flag_smooth_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/ggr/tn/Mexican_flag_smooth.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 20 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( Mexican_flag_smooth_gp ) {
    0,   0,255,  0,
   63,  42,255, 45,
  127, 255,255,255,
  191, 255, 55, 45,
  255, 255,  0,  0};

 // Gradient palette "Fire_2_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/ds/icons/tn/Fire-2.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 12 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( Fire_2_gp ) { //Red
    0, 255,255,  0,
  127, 255, 55,  0,
  255, 255,  0,  0};

  // Gradient palette "Orange_3D_1_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/sd/tn/Orange-3D_1.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 12 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( Orange_3D_1_gp ) {// Orange
    0, 255,111, 11,
  127, 255, 92,  2,
  255, 255, 74,  1};

  // Gradient palette "bhw2_grrrrr_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/bhw/bhw2/tn/bhw2_grrrrr.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 32 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( bhw2_grrrrr_gp ) {
    0, 184, 15,155,
   35,  78, 46,168,
   84,  65,169,230,
  130,   9,127,186,
  163,  77,182,109,
  191, 242,246, 55,
  216, 142,128,103,
  255,  72, 50,168};

// Gradient palette "es_skywalker_12_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/es/skywalker/tn/es_skywalker_12.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 16 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( es_skywalker_12_gp ) { // Blue
    0,  92,175,255,
   61,  20,100,255,
  153,   1, 10,170,
  255,   0,  1, 29};


// Gradient palette "es_candide_26_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/es/candide/tn/es_candide_26.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 24 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( es_candide_26_gp ) { //Purple
    0, 104, 10,245,
   89, 155,  0,245,
  165, 249,  2,242,
  208, 249, 51,247,
  249, 247,180,250,
  255, 247,180,250};

// Gradient palette "cool_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/h5/tn/cool.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 8 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( cool_gp ) { // Blue to purple
    0,   0,255,255,
  255, 255,  0,255};

// Gradient palette "green_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/h5/tn/green.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 8 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( green_gp ) {
    0, 255,255,255,
  255,   0,255,  0};

// Gradient palette "Pink_3D_2_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/sd/tn/Pink-3D_2.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 12 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( Pink_3D_2_gp ) { //Pink
    0, 244, 58,242,
  127, 222, 29,226,
  255, 201, 10,210};

// Gradient palette "GoldSunset_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/nd/atmospheric/tn/GoldSunset.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 36 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( GoldSunset_gp ) { //Yellow and Orange
    0, 229,118,  0,
   41, 227,101,  0,
   82, 224, 86,  0,
  118, 163, 42,  0,
  124, 113, 15,  0,
  129, 167, 68,  2,
  138, 237,164, 16,
  191, 232,139,  2,
  255, 229,118,  0};

// Gradient palette "Sunset_Real_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/nd/atmospheric/tn/Sunset_Real.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 28 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( Sunset_Real_gp ) { //Orange and blue
    0, 120,  0,  0,
   22, 179, 22,  0,
   51, 255,104,  0,
   85, 167, 22, 18,
  135, 100,  0,103,
  198,  16,  0,130,
  255,   0,  0,160};

// Gradient palette "Blue_Magenta_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/nd/basic/tn/Blue_Magenta.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 12 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( Blue_Magenta_gp ) { //Blue purple
    0,   0,  0,255,
  127,  42,  0,255,
  255, 255,  0,255};
  

// Gradient palette "Red_Yellow_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/nd/basic/tn/Red_Yellow.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 12 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( Red_Yellow_gp ) { //Red to yellow
    0, 255,  0,  0,
  127, 255, 55,  0,
  255, 255,255,  0};


// Gradient palette "Yellow_White_Magenta_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/nd/basic/tn/Yellow_White_Magenta.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 20 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( Yellow_White_Magenta_gp ) { //Yellow to white
    0, 255,255,  0,
   63, 255,255, 45,
  127, 255,255,255,
  191, 255, 55,255,
  255, 255,  0,255};

// Gradient palette "White_Cyan_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/nd/basic/tn/White_Cyan.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 12 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( White_Cyan_gp ) { //White to light blue
    0, 255,255,255,
  127,  42,255,255,
  255,   0,255,255};

// Gradient palette "Magenta_White_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/nd/basic/tn/Magenta_White.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 12 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( Magenta_White_gp ) { //Purple to white
    0, 255,  0,255,
  127, 255, 55,255,
  255, 255,255,255};

// Gradient palette "Magenta_Cyan_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/nd/basic/tn/Magenta_Cyan.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 12 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( Magenta_Cyan_gp ) { //purple to light blue
    0, 255,  0,255,
  127,  42, 55,255,
  255,   0,255,255};

  // Gradient palette "Green_Cyan_Blue_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/nd/basic/tn/Green_Cyan_Blue.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 20 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( Green_Cyan_Blue_gp ) { //Greent to light blue
    0,   0,255,  0,
   63,   0,255, 45,
  127,   0,255,255,
  191,   0, 55,255,
  255,   0,  0,255};


// Gradient palette "rhubarb_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/ocal/tn/rhubarb.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 20 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( rhubarb_gp ) { //purple to red
    0, 255, 55, 45,
   76, 255,  0,  0,
  127, 188, 12, 45,
  191, 255,  0,  0,
  255, 188, 12, 45};

// Gradient palette "YlGnBu_09_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/cb/seq/tn/YlGnBu_09.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 72 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( YlGnBu_09_gp ) { //Blue
    0, 255,255,170,
   28, 255,255,170,
   28, 210,239,102,
   56, 210,239,102,
   56, 133,209,106,
   84, 133,209,106,
   84,  41,157,117,
  113,  41,157,117,
  113,   7,121,132,
  141,   7,121,132,
  141,   1, 73,125,
  170,   1, 73,125,
  170,   1, 28, 89,
  198,   1, 28, 89,
  198,   1,  7, 65,
  226,   1,  7, 65,
  226,   1,  2, 17,
  255,   1,  2, 17};

  // Gradient palette "Oranges_09_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/cb/seq/tn/Oranges_09.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 72 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( Oranges_09_gp ) { //Orange
    0, 255,233,207,
   28, 255,233,207,
   28, 252,203,149,
   56, 252,203,149,
   56, 249,162, 82,
   84, 249,162, 82,
   84, 249,109, 29,
  113, 249,109, 29,
  113, 249, 69,  6,
  141, 249, 69,  6,
  141, 220, 36,  1,
  170, 220, 36,  1,
  170, 167, 15,  1,
  198, 167, 15,  1,
  198,  83,  8,  1,
  226,  83,  8,  1,
  226,  41,  4,  1,
  255,  41,  4,  1};


// Gradient palette "bhw1_28_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/bhw/bhw1/tn/bhw1_28.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 32 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( bhw1_28_gp ) {// Purple blue purple
    0,  75,  1,221,
   30, 252, 73,255,
   48, 169,  0,242,
  119,   0,149,242,
  170,  43,  0,242,
  206, 252, 73,255,
  232,  78, 12,214,
  255,   0,149,242};

  // Gradient palette "bhw2_10_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/bhw/bhw2/tn/bhw2_10.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 28 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( bhw2_10_gp ) { //Dark green to light green
    0,   0, 12,  0,
   61, 153,239,112,
  127,   0, 12,  0,
  165, 106,239,  2,
  196, 167,229, 71,
  229, 106,239,  2,
  255,   0, 12,  0};
// Gradient palette "bhw2_11_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/bhw/bhw2/tn/bhw2_11.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 20 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( bhw2_11_gp ) { //Dark grren and blue mixed
    0,   0, 12,  8,
   79,   0, 55, 45,
  130,   0,136,125,
  183,   0, 55, 45,
  255,   0, 12,  8};

// Gradient palette "bhw3_01_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/bhw/bhw3/tn/bhw3_01.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 52 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( bhw3_01_gp ) { //Pink, to blue, to red, to yellow
    0, 255,146,228,
   25, 152, 43, 65,
   48,  36, 17, 22,
   72,   8, 34, 75,
   81,   1, 58,170,
  104,  42, 49,245,
  124,  15, 15, 95,
  150,   1,  8, 39,
  175,  98, 32, 35,
  204, 123,  9,  2,
  219, 220, 15,  2,
  237, 255, 93,  6,
  255, 244,244,  0};

   // Gradient palette "Deep_Sea_gp", originally from
// http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/ggr/tn/Deep_Sea.png.index.html
// converted for FastLED with gammas (2.6, 2.2, 2.5)
// Size: 20 bytes of program space.

DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE( Deep_Sea_gp ) { //Dark blue
    0,   0,  1,  2,
  148,   1,  7, 24,
  194,   2, 31, 77,
  226,   1,108,144,
  255,   0,237,235};

// Single array of defined cpt-city color palettes.
// This will let us programmatically choose one based on
// a number, rather than having to activate each explicitly 
// by name every time.
// Since it is const, this array could also be moved 
// into PROGMEM to save SRAM, but for simplicity of illustration
// we'll keep it in a regular SRAM array.
//
// This list of color palettes acts as a "playlist"; you can
// add or delete, or re-arrange as you wish.
const TProgmemRGBGradientPalettePtr gGradientPalettes[] = {
  GoldSunset_gp,
  //Green_3D_1_gp,
  //GoldSunset_gp,
  //bhw1_33_gp,
  //bhw1_33_gp,
  //bhw1_33_gp,
  //bhw1_33_gp,
  //Green_3D_1_gp,
  //Fire_2_gp,
  yellow_gp,
  RK_Yellow_gp,
  //yellow_gp,
  //yellow_gp,
  //blues_gp,
  //blues_gp,
  //bhw1_33_gp,
  //bhw1_33_gp,
  //bhw1_33_gp,
 Fuschia_8_gp,
  //Blue_Green_gp,
  //Blue_Green_gp,
  //Fire_2_gp,
  //Green_Cyan_Blue_gp,
  //Green_Cyan_Blue_gp,
 //Green_Cyan_Blue_gp,
  //Green_Cyan_Blue_gp,
  //Green_Cyan_Blue_gp,
  //Green_Cyan_Blue_gp,
  //Green_3D_1_gp,
  //Green_3D_1_gp,
  //Mexican_flag_smooth_gp,
  //Mexican_flag_smooth_gp,
  //Fire_2_gp,
  //Fire_2_gp,
  //bhw1_33_gp,
  //es_skywalker_12_gp,
  //Fire_2_gp,
  //es_skywalker_12_gp,
  //es_skywalker_12_gp,
  //Orange_3D_1_gp,
  //Orange_3D_1_gp,
  //bhw2_grrrrr_gp,
  //es_candide_26_gp,
  //cool_gp,
  //cool_gp,
  //green_gp,
  //green_gp,
  //Pink_3D_2_gp,
  //Pink_3D_2_gp,
  //GoldSunset_gp,
  //Green_Cyan_Blue_gp,
  //Sunset_Real_gp,
  //Blue_Magenta_gp,
  //Blue_Magenta_gp,
  //Red_Yellow_gp,
  //Red_Yellow_gp,
  //Yellow_White_Magenta_gp,
  //White_Cyan_gp,
  //White_Cyan_gp,
  //Magenta_White_gp,
  //Magenta_White_gp,
  //Magenta_Cyan_gp,
  //Magenta_Cyan_gp,
  //Green_Cyan_Blue_gp,
  //Green_Cyan_Blue_gp,
  //rhubarb_gp,
  //YlGnBu_09_gp,
  //Oranges_09_gp,
  //bhw1_28_gp,
  //bhw2_10_gp,
  //bhw2_11_gp,
  //bhw3_01_gp,
  //Sunset_Real_gp,
  Sunset_Real_gp,
 };
//
// const TProgmemRGBGradientPalettePtr gGradientPalettes[] = {
// Fuschia_8_gp,
// };


// Count of how many cpt-city gradients are defined:
const uint8_t gGradientPaletteCount = 
  sizeof( gGradientPalettes) / sizeof( TProgmemRGBGradientPalettePtr );
```

Comment: separate the state transition and the resulting LED mode selection ... for example, at reset, go to state `0` ... in state `0`, if `solid` pressed, goto state `1`, if `palette` pressed, goto state `5` ... in state `1`, if `solid` pressed, goto state `2` ... in state `2`, if `solid` pressed, goto state `1` ... etc. etc. .............. then light LEDs according to existing state ... if state `2`, light random solid color and go to state `1` ... etc. etc. ...... basically, keep the state selection by button self contained ... the LED lighting is done only on basis of the state number